# When Opening A Html File Via An <a> Tag, It Doesnt Load Properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, href

i am creating a slider that increments from 0-50.
I have successfully accomplished my goals except 1.

I added a button which should load a separate html file.When i click this button it adds "?rangeInput=10" onto the end of the URL at the top of my browser.

What have i done wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateValue() {
var display = [];
var starter = [
'<table cellspacing="0" style="align:center;border:1px solid;">',
'<thead>',
'<td style="border-bottom:1px solid #000000;background-  color:#303030;width:1000px;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:20px;">',
'<p align="center" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:30px;"><strong>Starter Package</strong></p>',
'</td>',
'</thead>',
'<tbody>',
'<td style="background-color:#ffffff;">',
'<center>',
'<p><strong> In this Package You Will Get:<strong><p>',
'<p>10GB Hard Drive Storage Space</p>',
'<p>Unlimited Bandwidth Transfer Per Month</p>',
'<p>CPanel Control Panel</p>',
'<p>Unlimited Email Accounts</p>',
'<p>Unlimited Amount Of Space Used For The Email Accounts</p>',
'<br>',
'<br>',
'<p style="color:red"><strong>WARNING:</strong></p>',
'<p>With This Package You Will Need To Register A Domain</p>',
'<p>We Offer Domain Registration!</p>',
'<a href="Order-Form.htm"><button class="button" id="Order_Now" style="width:125;background-color:#303030;height:35;">Order Now</button></a>',
'</center>',
'</td>',
'</tbody>',
'</table>',
'<style>',
'button#Order_Now{',
'   -moz-border-radius:15px;',
'   -webkit-border-radius:15px;',
'   border-radius:15px;',
'}',
'</style>',
].join('');

var beginner = [
'<table cellspacing="0" style="align:center;border:1px solid;">',
'<thead>',
'<td style="border-bottom:1px solid #000000;background-color:#303030;width:1000px;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:20px;">',
'<p align="center" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:30px;"><strong>Beginner Package</strong></p>',
'</td>',
'</thead>',
'<tbody>',
'<td style="background-color:#ffffff;">',
'<center>',
'<p><strong> In this Package You Will Get:<strong><p>',
'<p>15GB Hard Drive Storage Space</p>',
'<p>Unlimited Bandwidth Transfer Per Month</p>',
'<p>CPanel Control Panel</p>',
'<p>Unlimited Email Accounts</p>',
'<p>Unlimited Amount Of Space Used For The Email Accounts</p>',
'<p><strong>This Also Includes A Domain which is yourname.com/.net/.uk/.org/</strong></p>',
'<a href="Order-Form.htm"><button class="button" id="Order_Now" style="width:125;background-color:#303030;height:35;">Order Now</button></a>',
'</center>',
'</td>',
'</tbody>',
'</table>',
'<style>',
'button#Order_Now{',
'   -moz-border-radius:15px;',
'   -webkit-border-radius:15px;',
'   border-radius:15px;',
'}',
'</style>'
].join('');

var advanced = [
'<table cellspacing="0" style="align:center;border:1px solid;">',
'<thead>',
'<td style="border-bottom:1px solid #000000;background-color:#303030;width:1000px;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:20px;">',
'<p align="center" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:30px;"><strong>Advanced Package</strong></p>',
'</td>',
'</thead>',
'<tbody>',
'<td style="background-color:#ffffff;">',
'<center>',
'<p><strong> In this Package You Will Get:<strong><p>',
'<p>25GB Hard Drive Storage Space</p>',
'<p>Unlimited Bandwidth Transfer Per Month</p>',
'<p>CPanel Control Panel</p>',
'<p>Unlimited Email Accounts</p>',
'<p>Unlimited Amount Of Space Used For The Email Accounts</p>',
'<p><strong>This Also Includes A Domain which is yourname.com/.net/.uk/.org/</strong></p>',
'<a href="Order-Form.htm"><button class="button" id="Order_Now" style="width:125;background-color:#303030;height:35;">Order Now</button></a>',
'</center>',
'</td>',
'</tbody>',
'</table>',
'<style>',
'button#Order_Now{',
'   -moz-border-radius:15px;',
'   -webkit-border-radius:15px;',
'   border-radius:15px;',
'}',
'</style>'
].join('');

var expert = [
'<table cellspacing="0" style="align:center;border:1px solid;">',
'<thead>',
'<td style="border-bottom:1px solid #000000;background-color:#303030;width:1000px;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:20px;">',
'<p align="center" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:30px;"><strong>Expert Package</strong></p>',
'</td>',
'</thead>',
'<tbody>',
'<td style="background-color:#ffffff;">',
'<center>',
'<p><strong> In this Package You Will Get:<strong><p>',
'<p>33GB Hard Drive Storage Space</p>',
'<p>Unlimited Bandwidth Transfer Per Month</p>',
'<p>CPanel Control Panel</p>',
'<p>Unlimited Email Accounts</p>',
'<p>Unlimited Amount Of Space Used For The Email Accounts</p>',
'<p><strong>This Also Includes A Domain which is yourname.com/.net/.uk/.org/</strong></p>',
'<a href="Order-Form.htm"><button class="button" id="Order_Now" style="width:125;background-color:#303030;height:35;">Order Now</button></a>',
'</center>',
'</td>',
'</tbody>',
'</table>',
'<style>',
'button#Order_Now{',
'   -moz-border-radius:15px;',
'   -webkit-border-radius:15px;',
'   border-radius:15px;',
'}',
'</style>'
].join('');

var business = [
'<table cellspacing="0" style="align:center;border:1px solid;">',
'<thead>',
'<td style="border-bottom:1px solid #000000;background-color:#303030;width:1000px;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:20px;">',
'<p align="center" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:30px;"><strong>Business Package</strong></p>',
'</td>',
'</thead>',
'<tbody>',
'<td style="background-color:#ffffff;">',
'<center>',
'<p><strong> In this Package You Will Get:<strong><p>',
'<p>Unlimited Hard Drive Storage Space</p>',
'<p>Unlimited Bandwidth Transfer Per Month</p>',
'<p>CPanel Control Panel</p>',
'<p>Unlimited Email Accounts</p>',
'<p>Unlimited Amount Of Space Used For The Email Accounts</p>',
'<p><strong>This Also Includes A Domain which is yourname.com/.net/.uk/.org/</strong></p>',
'<a href="Order-Form.htm"><button class="button" id="Order_Now"    style="width:125;background-color:#303030;height:35;">Order Now</button></a>',
'</center>',
'</td>',
'</tbody>',
'</table>',
'<style>',
'button#Order_Now{',
'   -moz-border-radius:15px;',
'   -webkit-border-radius:15px;',
'   border-radius:15px;',
'}',
'</style>'
].join('');


  var rangeInput = document.getElementById("rangeInput").value
  if (rangeInput == 0) {
  document.querySelector('.display').innerHTML = '';
  }
  if (rangeInput == 10) {
  document.querySelector('.display').innerHTML = starter;
  }
  if (rangeInput == 20) {
  document.querySelector('.display').innerHTML = beginner;
  }
  if (rangeInput == 30) {
  document.querySelector('.display').innerHTML = advanced;
  }
  if (rangeInput == 40) {
  document.querySelector('.display').innerHTML = expert;
  }
  if (rangeInput == 50) {
  document.querySelector('.display').innerHTML = business;
  }
}
</script>
<form oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value">
  <input type="range" id="rangeInput" name="rangeInput" step="10" value="0"     onchange="updateValue()" onmouseover="" min="0" max="50" >
  <div class="display"></div>
  <div align="center" style="font-size:25px;">
</form>

<div id="text" align="left" style="font-size:25px;padding-left:250px;">    </div>

<style>
input[type="range"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 1003px;
    height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: #0066FF;
    align:left-middle;
    padding-left:0px;

}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: #FFF;
    cursor:move;
}
*:focus {
    outline: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
input[type="range"]:focus{
    -webkit-appearance:
}
</style>
```

Sorry that all of this is really messy and all in one file , i am not really good at referencing CSS files and stuff, im really really new to HTML and i am trying to teach myself. At the moment i have like 14 different tabs on random crap on HTML because this is really killing my brain! It worked before like each variable , e.g starter, if i was to put that into a separate html file and run it. The button would work perfectly! :( Is it something to do with me setting and displaying it in a div tag?

Comment: What made you think it was a good idea to put all your HTML in Javascript arrays ?

Comment: It's not even HTML anymore! The arrays!

Comment: it was an easy way for me to display the table and stuff the way i wanted it to

Comment: Take your HTML out of your arrays or I will become very sad :(

Comment: So what you are doing is creating content based off of `rangeInput` value, but all of this content should already be on the page as real HTML and then you should be hiding/showing the content based on `rangeInput` value.

Comment: Can you indicate a better way for me to display all this stuff?

Answer (score 6):

You are mixing responsibilities here. Your HTML should be describing the document and Javascript making it dynamic. You are basically using your Javascript to describe your document with HTML hence you coming up with strange problems along the way.

You are pretty much putting your HTML in sections and then printing the sections with JavaScript.

You should instead put all of your HTML in your page, identify them with IDs and then use JavaScript to show them or hide them based on their IDs using selectors.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem of defining your HTML in JS has been covered well, so I'm just going to focus on your question itself.

When you use the `<button>` element, its default `type` is `submit`, which means when you click it, it will submit the form. Since you don't specify an `action` for your form, when it's submitted it will load the current page with the values of all of the form fields. Since you don't specify a `method` for your form, it defaults to `get`, which means that the values of any of the form fields get added as querystring parameters to your URL. That's the "?rangeInput=10" that you're seeing.

I can't explain how it worked when you had things in separate files, but my guess is that you weren't including the form element on those pages. Without a form to submit, the button wouldn't actually be doing anything, so the click event would bubble up to the anchor, which would then open the page it's linking to.

You can prevent the button from submitting the form by adding `type=button` to it. But really, having a button inside an anchor (`<a>`) tag is really weird. They are both meant to handle mouse clicks, so one of them is almost always going to be pointless.

If you just want to open Order-Form.htm, then you can remove the button completely, as that's what the anchor is designed for. If you want to open Order-Form.htm and also pass in the value of `rangeInput`, then you can remove the anchor, leave the button as-is, and add `action=Order-Form.htm` to your form element. That way clicking the button will submit the form, along with the values of all form fields, to Order-Form.htm.